# RxJava Transforming Map into List

Tags: rx-java

Here's desired behavior:

```
[A: 4, B: 2, C: 3, D: 3] -> [A,A,A,A,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D]
```

I wrote some code to tackle this.. Here's the code:

```
Map<String, Integer> terms = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(terms.entrySet())
    .flatMap(entry -> {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
            items.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        return Stream.of(items);
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm relatively new to Rx, so I want to know if there's a best practice or something like that.

Comment: It would be easier in Kotlin even without Rx: `map.flatMap { entry -> (0 until entry.value).map { entry.key } }`. But with Java I think you have to try solution of @Niraj Chauhan

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Thanks Andrey! Unfortunately I can't use Kotlin now.. I'll give it a try later in my persona project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
terms.keySet().stream()
    .map(s -> IntStream.range(0, map.get(s))
            .mapToObj(i -> s).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```